# displaying label in different form with if else, vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, if-statement

i have 2 forms. let's say form2 has a label that is not visible but with a particular "if" statement in form1, it will show up? here's my current code in form1 that isn't working:

```
Private Sub btnEnterPromoCode_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnEnterPromoCode.Click

    Dim pcode As String
    pcode = InputBox("Please enter any promo code below.", "Promo Code")

    If pcode = "05567" Then

        Dim resultz As Integer = MessageBox.Show("You have entered the 'Promo of the Week'.", "Promo Code Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        frmCheckOut.lblFree.Show()

    ElseIf pcode = "66795" Then

        Dim resultx As Integer = MessageBox.Show("You have entered the 'Christmas Promo'.", "Promo Code Successful", MessageBoxButtons.OK)

        frmCheckOut.lblFree.Show()

    ElseIf pcode = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong code", "Promo Code Unsuccessful", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("You have entered a wrong code", "Promo Code Unsuccessful", MessageBoxButtons.OK)
    End If

End Sub
```

sorry, kinda new with vb.net. thanks!! and anyway, in my code, checkout is the form2.

Comment: Are you sure that the label's .Text property has been set? (If it was a blank label, you wouldn't be able to see it)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that frmCheckOut is a class name, not a reference to an instance of the class. When loading the second form, save a member-level or global reference to it. then use that reference in the call to Show.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim f As New Form2
    f.Show()
    f.Label1.BackColor = Drawing.Color.PeachPuff
    f.Label1.Show()
End Sub
```

Having said that, I would have never thought to use `f.Label1.Show()` I would have used: `f.Label1.Visible = True`  (I also normally don't use PeachPuff as a color, but that's a story for a different day).

As @JerryM already said, it looks like you are calling the form directly and not an instance of it (which is what I did in my example). That makes me think you may have to rethink the design of the application a little...